# How do I choose not to display the title header on a specific page?

Tags: php, title, page-specific-settings

I would like to have one specific page on my WordPress blog omit the header .

Is there a way to wrap that title code from page.php in my WordPress theme in an if clause that specifies the page I do not want the title to appear on? For instance, if page is 135, do not display title, else display.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if  you want it by ID (which might or might not be good idea, depending on how likely ID will stay same for a long time - no migrations, etc) that would be something like:

```
if( !is_page(135) ) {

    //  code goes here
}
```

See [Conditional Tags > Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page) in Codex for more.

Alternative way would be to do this in some filter, as opposed to editing template files.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. How would a filter work?

Comment: @macreator that would entirely depend on what and how much you want to hide (single function with filter available - easy, multiple function or without handy filters - hard).

Comment: Got it. I think I'll stick with the conditional tag above. One question I have though is how can I put the title code within the tag? What I have so far is: <?php if( !is_page(135) ) {

echo"<h2 class='posttitle'><?php the_title(); ?></h2>"; 
}?>  But for obvious reasons the php title code doesn't work when encapsulated in php code.

Comment: @macreator your syntax there makes no sense in PHP - even if you are echoing HTML you are still in PHP context there, should be something around `echo "<h2 class='posttitle'>"; the_title(); echo "</h2>";`